# Copy GIF to UIPasteboard

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa, gif, uipasteboard

I'm trying to copy a GIF image to the UIPasteboard in swift, at the moment it only copies the static version of the image and seems to convert it to PNG looking at the file extension when I upload it somewhere.

Wondered if anyone had any idea how to achieve this? All other soltions I've found only seem to work when getting NSData from a URL rather than from an image in the bundle

Comment: Please show how you're currently copying the image to the pasteboard.

Comment: I'm using `UIPasteboard.generalPasteboard().image = imageToCopy` for copying the GIF currently.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For anyone who ever encounters this problem I managed to find a solution

```
let url: NSURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("\(self.imageNames[indexPath.row])", withExtension: ".gif")!
let data: NSData = NSData(contentsOfURL: url)!
UIPasteboard.generalPasteboard().setData(data, forPasteboardType: "com.compuserve.gif")
```

As it turns out you do need to use a URL and extract the `NSData` of the GIF from that URL.

Here I am getting the URL of the GIF that is in my bundle, searching for it using the name and extension of the image. I am then setting the data in the pasteboard and bingo we have an animated GIF when pasting the result from the pasteboard

Comment: how can I load if I will get the .gif files dynamically from the server?

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't look like the image property on the pasteboard supports the GIF type.

> [The associated array of representation types is UIPasteboardTypeListImage, which includes types kUTTypePNG and kUTTypeJPEG.](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPasteboard_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIPasteboard/image)

You could probably do this using the `NSData` from the GIF though:

```
import MobileCoreServices

// ...

var image = UIImage(...)
let data = NSData(bytes: &image, length: sizeof(UIImage))
UIPasteboard.generalPasteboard().setData(data, forPasteboardType: kUTTypeGIF as String)) // com.compuserve.gif
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! This largely works and does set the image as a GIF but unfrotunately doesn't convert it to an 'image'. Instead when I copy the contents of the clipboard into messages for example it will show up as a file and not as a viewable GIF that it would do with an app like GIPHY. Thanks

Comment: Hmm, ok I'll have to keep thinking of a better implementation.

Comment: It must be something to do with the way the NSData is being created because the same thing happens when setting the pasteboard type as PNG or JPEG. Also the size of the file that is being sent is only 8 bytes which obviously can't be right