# React Native Giphy Clipboard Not Animated

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo, giphy

I've somehow successfully gotten a Giphy url to copy into the Clipboard first time I tried (lucky me) but when I paste it to Notes it just shows a still image...is there a way to get it to animate (iMessage) like other apps do on paste?

I'm just downloading the Giphy URL, loading the file in base64 and then paste to clipboard using [Expo Clipboard](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/clipboard/)

```js
const source = await ReactNativeBlobUtil.config({
  fileCache: true,
}).fetch('GET', item.body?.media?.url);

const local = await source.path();

const base64 = await RNFS.readFile(local, 'base64');

await Clipboard.setImageAsync(base64);
```

I know this is a minimal code example, but I'm sort of just hoping someone who knows what this is can just answer the question :)

There is something with iOS here but I don't have direct access:

[Copy GIF to UIPasteboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33675297/copy-gif-to-uipasteboard)

Comment: please give us base64 value i doubt it